# Delete user in ASP.NET Identity and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I need to delete a user, his roles and the UserTitle (many-to-many) entities for the user. I want to do this in one transaction, the db context and userManager are injected into controller. Do I need to use SaveChangesAsync in this scenario, or is transaction.Commit enough to push changes to the database?

```
var userTitles = db.UserTitles
    .Where(ut => ut.UserId == user.Id);

using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (var userTitle in userTitles.ToList())
        db.UserTitles.Remove(userTitle);

    foreach (var item in rolesForUser.ToList())
        await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, item);

    await userManager.DeleteAsync(user);

    transaction.Commit();
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Nothing will be pushed to the database until you call save changes.  So committing the transaction before saving the changes won't do anything.

Comment: @TGnat, should I then call transaction.Commit after saving changes to db?

Comment: Yes, although EF may already be wrapping save changes in a transaction of its own.

Comment: @TGnat "Avoid answering questions in the comments".